# Earth gravitational potential

Tags: perturbation-theory, spherical-harmonics

In the Cook's "Perturbations of satellite orbits by tesseral harmonics" i've found the following formula(13, page 799) for potential:
$$U = \frac{\mu}{r}\left\{1-\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{R}{r}\right)^n\left[J_nP_n(\sin\phi)-\sum_{s=1}^{n}J_{n,s}P_n^s\sin\phi\cos{s(\lambda - \lambda_{n,s})}\right]   \right\}$$
What values are taken as $\lambda_{n,s}$ and $J_{n,s}$? There were some words about it in the book, but not the exact values.

Comment: The values you are searching are the result of measurements and fits. Have a look at EGM-2008 or JGM-3.

Comment: @kvantour, thank you for your answer. Can you provide some actual links to this models so the question could be closed?

Comment: http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/egm08_wgs84.html